# How to invoke a service registered in WSO2 governance registry?

Tags: web-services, repository, wso2, wso2-bam

I have registered a service in wso2 greg. So do I get a separate URL to invoke that service via greg, so that I can track the service statistics like total invokes, average time taken etc. and export it to wso2 BAM server?
Or is there any another way to track service statistics registered on WSO2 greg using WSO2 BAM server?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but this is the theory;

As WSO2 G-Reg too is a Carbon based product, you can install the Service Statistics feature as a normal Carbon server. Make sure you use the feature repository with correct version. If everything works as expected, you should be able to invoke the service from the hosted service URL and should be able to monitor the service with Service statics feature, and send data to BAM. And also you can use ESB to monitor the hosted service and monitor it inside ESB proxy service. For more details refer [1].

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/07/monitoring-a-web-service-via-esb-analyzing-and-visualizing-results-using-bam/